# Error in get_sentiments function

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis, tidytext

Has anyone used 'tidytextmining' for sentiment analysis in R? 
[Tidytextmining](http://tidytextmining.com/sentiment.html)

I am using **R V 3.4.1** and I am getting the following error for this piece of code.

```
library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)
get_sentiments("afinn")
```

Error - Error in get_sentiments("afinn") : 
  could not find function "get_sentiments"

I have the right package installed and the library reference. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and it's working just fine. Are you sure you have the right library reference? I would double-check!

Comment: My mistake! it was a package installation issue one of the dependent package - "rlang" was missing. It is working now. Thank you.